# What is the best way to enable development hot reloading when not using pheonix?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, plug

So I'm learning Elixir and Pheonix looked too much to start learning, so I make a simple JSON Rest API with Plug and Poison, but to see any changes I need to stop the server and run `mix run --no-halt` again. I came from nodeJS and it has `nodemon` that just tracks all files that depend from root module and reloads the whole server if it sees any changes. Is there something similar for mix or elixir. I know you can reload specific parts of the code with OTP, it would be the best if my server did that on save, but right now I just want a faster response of what I've done. Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never was a big fan of hot reloading; what works for me, you start the project as `iex -S mix ...` and issue [`recompile`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#recompile/1) from `iex` console whenever you need the code to be reloaded.

That makes you full control on what version is currently running and preserves the system from unwanted attempts to recompile a WIP-code.

If you still want it to be automated, check [`Lettuce`](https://hexdocs.pm/lettuce) package.